# How to not have consent page in OpenID Connect Authorize Endpoint for Resource Owner?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect

When I had resource owner grant type, I never needed to deal with the Consent Page but now I am trying to create SSO for my systems using OpenID Connect and I am very confused. `/authorize` endpoint always shows consent form for public apis (Facebook, Google etc) as this used to be the endpoint that was used for public apis most often.

With OpenID Connect, the `/authorize` endpoint seems to be doing the authentication and authorization, so how should I be handling the consent page. My ONLY thought is to check if the client has grant type `password` and if it does, do not show the consent form and just proceed the request with `authorized = true`. Is this a correct approach? There is nothing written in the specification on that (or at least I didn't see anything about it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3 for the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant the user credentials are presented in a call to the token endpoint, not the authorization endpoint. The latter is only used for the Authorization Code grant.

Upon sending the authorization request back to the client, it is up to the discretion of the Authorization Server to present a consent screen for release of the information. According to the spec the Authorization Server should present it in a consumer scenario but one may choose to disable it in an enterprise scenario. That would be an implementation specific option to configure in the Authorization Server.

Comment: Yes I know that but I would like to have a single sign on, which wouldn't be possible with token endpoint.  So I need to have authorization endpoint with openid

Comment: added more on using consent with the authorization code grant; remember, the grant type "password" refers to the resource owner password credentials grant which will not use the authorization endpoint